# Is collection of subsets of $\Omega$ that are determined by first n number of coin tosses a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $F_n$ be the collection of subsets of $\Omega$ whose occurrence can be decided by looking at the first n tosses. How can I show $F_n$ is a $\sigma$- algebra?

Comment: I don't understand what "determined by the first n tosses" means.

Comment: For example,Let $A_1$ be the set of all elements of Ω such that there are exactly 2 heads during the first 4 coin tosses. Then, $A_1 ∈ F_4$.

Comment: This problem seems to require you to do two things. First, say exactly what $F_n$ is --- not "for example" as in your comment but a mathematically precise definition. Second, combine that and the definition of "$\sigma$-algebra" to determine exactly what you need to prove. Technically, there's a third step, namely to prove those things, but I think that, once you've got the goals written down exactly, they will be very easy to prove.  (P.S. I'm not saying that your "For example" comment won't clarify for @DanielWainfleet what you intended, but something more precise is needed for a proof.)

Answer (score 0):

So, $\Omega$ is the infinite product $\Pi_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \{H, T\}$. The sets you're looking at are such that if $x \in A \in F_n$ then $y \in A$ if $x_i = y_i$ for all $i <= n$.

These are finite collections of sets. You should be able to find most of the proof yourself. I would suggest proving that they're an algebra and then using something that says "finite algebras are $\sigma$-algebras".